# WP8 - Exception on connecting to sqlite database

Tags: sqlite, windows-phone-8

I'm running into a strange issue when connecting to a local sqlite database on Windows Phone 8.  When testing the app locally after deploying with VS, I'm able to connect to the database without any issues and run queries.

However, when I run the app after downloading it from the Store, I receive the following exception upon attempting to connect to the database:

```
Could not open database file: 'Version=3,uri=file:mydbname.sqlite' (CannotOpen)
   at SQLite.SQLiteConnection.ctor(String databasePath, SQLiteOpenFlags openFlags, Boolean storeDateTimeAsTicks)
```

I should note that after receiving this exception, the query goes through and returns the expected data (seemingly without issue), which confirms that the db does indeed exist on the device after installing it from the Store.

The database path in the exception is the same as the one I've seen while debugging so I'm not sure why I'm getting an error.  I'm using sqlite-net-wp8 v3.8.4.3.

I've seen this post (but it seems to not be limited to the Store): [I cannot create SQLiteConnection in PCL version of Sqlite.net on WP8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20873946/i-cannot-create-sqliteconnection-in-pcl-version-of-sqlite-net-on-wp8)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing my db path from 'Version 3, uri=file:mydbname.sqlite' to use `ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path + 'mydbname.sqlite'` seems to have solved this problem.